# Preventing Multiple Decimal Points

Tags: regex, decimal

I'm not a computer science person and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent a user from entering in more than one decimal point.  For example, how do I stop someone from entering 3..5?

Comment: Search for `..` and chastise them appropriately.

Comment: @tchrist: won't catch things like `3.14.159`.

Answer (score 1):

The background given in the question is practically non-existent, but the proper way to do this would be try to parse the input with whatever language you are using, and if it fails, reject it. But if you want a regex:

```
^\d+\.\d+$    # allows numbers with a single decimal point; 
                fails if it doesn't have one
^\d+(\.\d+)?$ # allows numbers with a decimal point or without one
```

Note these regexes allow an unlimited number of digits on either side of the decimal point. If you want to specify the number of digits, you can use `{m...n}` instead of the `+` quantifier:

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$   # allows numbers from 0.0 to 999.999
```

---

**EDIT:**  If you want to allow input of the form `.25` like tchrist suggests, you could use :

```
^\d*\.\d+?$
```

Comment: Why not simply check if it has 2 decimal points, and if it does, reject? `.*\..*\..*`

Comment: I thought he was just trying to prevent 2 decimal points. It seems that the OP somehow knows that he has only digits and periods. Well, rather safe than sorry, I guess.

Comment: It fails on the commonly seenly and completely valid floating point notation `.25`.

Comment: ^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$    This is what I have so far. What would I add to this specific expression so that it also won't allow multiple decimal points?

Comment: When a user enters multiple decimal points, it removes their answer, and it crashes if they try to move to the next page.  Instead of this, I want it to fire a validation to make them change it.

Comment: @Ramzi What are you using/doing?

Comment: I'm creating a survey and I don't want them to put in mulitple decimal points within an open field.  I'm using .net

Comment: You mean you want to prevent them from entering invalid values in the first place.  That's not a job for regexes, just use a formatted field.

Comment: No, I want to allow entry of incorrect values but not let them move on until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For a floating-point number, ie ###.##, you can match

```
^[0-9]+[.]{1}[0-9]{1,2}$
```

This will allow any number of digits, followed by a single decimal (required) followed by one or 2 digits.

Comment: No, that does not allow any number of digits.  `/^ (?: \. \d{1,2} | \d+ (?: \. \d{0,2} )? ) $/x` does.

Comment: @tchrist Any particular reason why you put `?:` in your capture groups? (I know what it does)

Comment: @NullUserException: To make them less captivating, but of course! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m{
    ^ (?: \. \d{1,2}   # eg: ".25"
        | \d+          # eg: "2343409823409823049823094823094820389402984230948"
              (?:
                  \. \d{0,2}
              )?       #  eg: "186282.42"
      ) 
    $
}x
```